# which css unit I need to use so that there will be no scroll in the page for all resolutions (Basic laptop resolution and 1920X1080 FHD resolution))

Tags: css

I tried giving the height of the image in `vh`. It worked in `1600X900` resolution and `1920*1080` resolution without any blank space or scroll in the page.

But in `1366X768` resolution it's giving scroll in the page.

```
<img class="layout-img">

.layout {
  height: 90vh;
}
```

Also I tried giving minimum height and grow slowly based on `viewport`

```
.layout {
      height: calc(550px +2vh);
    }
```

Can you suggest which `css` unit I need to use?

Comment: Please add some relevant code to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

layout with no scroll and image will be fit on every screen.

```css
 .body-noscroll{
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  .full-width-image{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Noscroll</title>
</head>
<body class="body-noscroll">
  <img            src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"      alt="Trulli" class="full-width-image">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't give `100vw` and `100vh` as along with the image there will be additional content on either sides and above the image

Comment: ok, can you clarify your question once, or put a screenshot or layout diagram, which you are planning to do, I can help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

To have no scrollbar if your image is bigger then the viewport can be simply done by adding overflow: hidden; to the image parent. Please see the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zk3Lbo87/

```
section {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```